# Selenium - Python - Javascript drop-down menu option value

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Any thoughts on how to select and click on one of the two drop down options for this code snippet. I have tried numerous approaches suggested in the forum, but could not get any to work.  Thanks in advance!

```
 <div class="dropdownButton">
    <li id="Li1" class="r_dd1" onclick="showDropdown1(event,this);">
        <a class="r_ddh1" id="columnYearType">10 Years</a>
        <ul style="display: block;">
            <li><a href="javascript:SRT_stocFund.CurrentPeriod(5, this)">5&nbsp;<span class="columnType">Years</span></a></li>

            <li><a href="javascript:SRT_stocFund.CurrentPeriod(10, this)">
                10 <span class="columnType">
                    Years
                                        </span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</div>
```

The xpath for the javascript:SRT_stocFund.CurrentPeriod 5 and 10 year options are:

```
//*[@id="Li1"]/ul/li[1]/a

//*[@id="Li1"]/ul/li[2]/a
```

Comment: Solved this by executing 2 steps. First step - activated the                          <li id="Li1" class="r_dd1" onclick="showDropdown1(event,this);"> with driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Li1"]').click()                            then second step activated                                                                     <li><a href="javascript:SRT_stocFund.CurrentPeriod(10, this)" with select = (driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Li1"]/ul/li[2]/a')).click()   Big clue was that I kept getting selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException until the first step was added.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will work:

```
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//path_to_drop_down")));
select.deselectAll();
select.selectByVisibleText("10 Years");
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: When I try this with and interactive session of iPython I get an invalid syntax on the second select  in the statement -"Select select = ".  Tried several variations and still get the syntax errors. I'm new to this, so please forgive if I'm doing this incorrectly.

Comment: What was the code that you tried and what error message did you get?